# CodeIgniter: error loading custom library

Tags: php, codeigniter

I created a custom Library in CodeIgniter, and positioned it in `application/libraries/VarMatrixSpecanimal.php`

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class VarMatrixSpecanimal {
    protected $variabiliMatrix;

    public function __construct() {
        $variabiliMatrix['cat']['no']=1;
        $variabiliMatrix['dog']['a']=2;
        $variabiliMatrix['bird']['b']=3;
    }

    public function get_matrix() {
        return $this->variabiliMatrix;
    }
}
?>
```

Then in one controller (`application/controllers/certificate.php`) method I added these two lines of code:

```
public function save1()
{
    //..... some more code before

    $this->load->library('VarMatrixSpecanimal');
    $numerical_values = $this->varmatrixspecanimal->get_matrix();
    //..... some more code after
```

But when I call save1 method, I get this error:

> A PHP Error was encountered
>   Severity: Notice
>   Message: Undefined property: Certificate::$varmatrixspecanimal
>   Filename: controllers/certificate.php
>   Line Number: 139

I don't understand where I do wrong, please help me.
I checked also CodeIgniter help http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/creating_libraries.html but I was not able to get my error

Comment: which class does your Controller extend from? CI_Controller?

Comment: When you load library try just making the first letter of class upper case only `Varmatrixspecanimal.php` and `class Varmatrixspecanimal {}` then `$this->load->library('varmatrixspecanimal');`

Comment: when you load library in controller then used small letter of library name. like this..`$this->load->library('varMatrixSpecanimal');` but first letter of library class name must be upper case.

Comment: Yes my controller extends CI_Controller

Comment: @wolfgang1983 I changed class definition this way `class Varmatrixspecanimal {....}` and renamed the filename to `Varmatrixspecanimal.php`<br/>Then I called `$this->load->library('varmatrixspecanimal');`..... but I got the same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add get_instance() function in constructor in VarMatrixSpecanimal.php

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->variabiliMatrix =& get_instance();

}
```

After this load library on your controller

```
$this->load->library('varmatrixspecanimal');
```

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced anything like this because I forgot this line of code: 
`parent::__construct`
in my __construct or constructor.

Comment: sorry, `parent::__construct();`

Answer (score 0):

Add include file with correct path at the top of program will solve this issue.

```
include "../../VarMatrixSpecanimal.php";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your constructor from this:

```
public function __construct() {
    $variabiliMatrix['cat']['no']=1;
    $variabiliMatrix['dog']['a']=2;
    $variabiliMatrix['bird']['b']=3;
}
```

to this:

```
public function __construct() {
    $this->variabiliMatrix['cat']['no']=1;
    $this->variabiliMatrix['dog']['a']=2;
    $this->variabiliMatrix['bird']['b']=3;
}
```

Also, when loading your library i think you don't need to uppercase any letters